# How to log into Trello Account with Email and Password using Trello API?

Tags: c#, api, postman, trello

I'm trying to access to my Trello account using my Email and Password via Postman, but I can't get it.

It works fine using OAuth 1.0 when proving my

- Key
- Secret Token
- Generate Access Token

in Postman, but that's not what I want.

Trello-API-Docu:
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/guides/rest-api/api-introduction/

---

Basically, I'm building an App which I want the user to log in to his Trello account by providing his Email and Password.

This my implemented API Request code:

```
public class LoginRequest
    {
        private const string url = "https://api.trello.com/....";

        public async Task<bool> CheckIfLoginPossible(string username, string password)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var authData = string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password);
            string authHeaderValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authData));
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authHeaderValue);
            HttpResponseMessage getHttpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(url + "" + "username=" + username + "&" + "password=" + password);
            var authorizationSuccessful = getHttpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode;

            if (authorizationSuccessful)
            {
                UserDetails.Username = username;
                UserDetails.Password = password;
            }
            return authorizationSuccessful;
        }
    }
```

In Trello's API-Docu it's not clear how to use your Email and password, in order to get access to your account, so I'm a bit confused now.

It would be nice if someone could guide me.

Thanks in advance :)